# Ordenamiento burbujeo con lista de objetos

Tags: java

Tengo una inquietud de como puedo usar el método burbuja para ordenar un *ArrayList* de objetos, para ponerlos en contexto dejare el ejercicio.

El ejercicio que estoy realizando me dice. Un viajero conoce todos los gastos que hizo en su ultimo viaje con la tarjeta de crédito, fueron 5 en total, los cuales se pueden clasificar en cuatro tipo: comida, hospedaje, transporte y ropa.

Tengo una clase viajero y la clase principal(main).

En la clase principal tengo tengo un vector y arrayList una pero no entiendo como puedo ordenar esa lista pensaba ordenar el vector por valor de comida que seria en la posición 450 o de que otra manera podría ordenarlo, no si me hice entender xd.

public class Viajero {

```
public Double comida, hospedaje, transporte, ropa;

public Viajero() {
}

public Viajero(Double comida, double hospedaje, double transporte, double ropa) 
{
    this.comida = comida;
    this.hospedaje = hospedaje;
    this.transporte = transporte;
    this.ropa = ropa;
}

public double getComida() {
    return comida;
}

public void setComida(double comida) {
    this.comida = comida;
}

public double getHospedaje() {
    return hospedaje;
}

public void setHospedaje(double hospedaje) {
    this.hospedaje = hospedaje;
}

public double getTransporte() {
    return transporte;
}

public void setTransporte(double transporte) {
    this.transporte = transporte;
}

public double getRopa() {
    return ropa;
}

public void setRopa(double ropa) {
    this.ropa = ropa;
}



}


 public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Viajero> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    vi[0] = new Viajero(450.000, 400.000, 400.000, 960.000);
    vi[1] = new Viajero(350.000, 705.000, 605.000, 900.0000);
    vi[2] = new Viajero(250.000, 850.000, 460.000, 300.0000);
    vi[3] = new Viajero(280.000, 950.000, 560.000, 400.0000);

    lista.add(vi[1]);
    lista.add(vi[2]);
    lista.add(vi[3]);
}
```

Comment: En dónde declaras vi?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Quiza lo que se te complicaba era como asignarle el nuevo elemento a esa posicion de la lista. Usando la estructura de lista podes utilizar el metodo

```
set(acaVaElIndexQueQueresCambiar, nuevoViajero)
```

El metodo quedaria asi

```
public static void ordenarLista(ArrayList<Viajero> lista) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < lista.size(); j++) {
            if(lista.get(i).getComida() < lista.get(j).getComida()) {
                Viajero aux = lista.get(i);
                lista.set(i, lista.get(j));
                lista.set(j, aux);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: voy analizarlos, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Acá tienes algunos ejemplos.

```
public static void burbuja_descendente(ArrayList<Viajero>arreglo){
    for(int i=0;i<arreglo.size();i++){
        Viajero temporal;
        for(int j=i+1;j<arreglo.size();j++){
            if(arreglo.get(i).getComida()<arreglo.get(j).getComida()){
                temporal=arreglo.get(j);
                arreglo.set(j,arreglo.get(i));
                arreglo.set(i,temporal);
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void burbuja_ascendente(ArrayList<Viajero>arreglo){
    for(int i=0;i<arreglo.size();i++){
        Viajero temporal;
        for(int j=i+1;j<arreglo.size();j++){
            if(arreglo.get(i).getComida()>arreglo.get(j).getComida()){
                temporal=arreglo.get(j);
                arreglo.set(j,arreglo.get(i));
                arreglo.set(i,temporal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Para probarlos:

```
burbuja_descendente(lista);
System.out.println(lista);

burbuja_ascendente(lista);
System.out.print(lista);
```

Answer (score 0):

En caso de que no quieras usar el **método burbuja** y ahorrar código podrías hacer esto:

```
ArrayList.Sort();
```

Ordena ascendentemente, no hace falta asignar el resultado a ninguna variable:

```
var ordenadoB = arrayList.Sort().Reverse();
```

Ordena descendentemente, aquí si se asigna el resultado a una variable.

Por supuesto hay muchísimas formas de hacer esto,  este es solo un ejemplo.